# Creating a yaml build template with access to all repositories

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build that uses the Azure DevOps REST api to do analysis across a collection of repositories in a single Azure DevOps project.

To speed up the build, it only checks out a single repository containing certain build utilities, such as powershell scripts - the rest of the analysis is done via querying specific information via the REST api.

**NOTE:** This build is running on Azure DevOps Server 2020, which still calls the setting "Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories". Looking at doc history, I believe this is equivalent to "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipeline", I use the more recent term below.

This all worked fine until "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines" was turned on.  With that setting turned on, the REST api only returns information about the repository containing the build utilities. This is due to the reduced scope of the Job Access Token (see [Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protect-access-to-repositories-in-yaml-pipelines))

I've attempted to create a template containing the list of all repositories, so that a few select builds can continue to easily access all repositories. Previously, no explicit list of repositories was needed, but now it appears they will have to manually be listed, and I'd like to do that in a single file.

Both yaml files below are in the same repository.

Template allRepos.yaml:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: steps
  type: stepList
  default: []

jobs:
- job:
  pool: 'swimming'
  uses:
    repositories:
    - R1
    - R2
    - R3
    - Rnnn
  steps:
    - ${{ parameters.steps }}
```

Yaml for pipeline:

```yaml
extends:
  template: allRepos.yaml
  parameters:
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: multiRepoAnalysis
      inputs:
        filePath: analysis.ps1
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

It seems like this should work according to:

- [access tokens - Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protect-access-to-repositories-in-yaml-pipelines))
- [repos - Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#protect-access-to-repositories-in-yaml-pipelines)
- [jobs.job definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines)

However, attempting to run this pipeline results in the errors:

```
Job 'Job1' references the repository 'R1' which is not defined by the pipeline.
Job 'Job1' references the repository 'R2' which is not defined by the pipeline.
Job 'Job1' references the repository 'R3' which is not defined by the pipeline.
Job 'Job1' references the repository 'Rnnn' which is not defined by the pipeline.
```

How can I create a template that:

- allows the access token for specific builds to access all repositories when "Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines" is turned on
- do so without checking out each repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Limitations

1. This solution only works for a list of at most 20 repositories
2. `- checkout: self` counts toward the 20 repository limit
3. You must include submodule repositories in the list, which also counts toward the 20 repository limit.

Exceeding 20 repositories will still result in an error:

```
##[error]Tokens may be scoped to a maximum of 20 repositories. Reference fewer repositories in YAML or disable Scoped Tokens.
```

This limitation could be worked around by splitting the build into multiple definitions - but note if your analysis includes accessing submodule repositories, those submodule repositories must be referenced in any list of the primary repositories.

To my current knowledge, there is not a way to scope the access token *for a particular pipeline* with a generic "all repositories" permission.

## Solution

The original templates were on the right track - but missed the fact that any `uses:` repositories must previously have been declared as a `resources:` repository.

There is a github issue to clarify the Microsoft documentation: [uses: keyword is not explained, does not work as described](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10461)

The working solution is:

Template allRepos.yaml:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: steps
  type: stepList
  default: []

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: R1
    type: git
    name: MyDevOpsProject/R1
  - repository: R2
    type: git
    name: MyDevOpsProject/R2
  - repository: R3
    type: git
    name: MyDevOpsProject/R3
  - repository: Rnnn
    type: git
    name: MyDevOpsProject/Rnnn

jobs:
- job:
  pool: 'swimming'
  uses:
    repositories:
    - R1
    - R2
    - R3
    - Rnnn
  steps:
    - ${{ parameters.steps }}
```

Yaml for pipeline:

```yaml
extends:
  template: allRepos.yaml
  parameters:
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: multiRepoAnalysis
      inputs:
        filePath: analysis.ps1
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```